# Problemas con reenvió de puertos Virtual Box

Tags: debian, virtualbox, bitnami

Tengo una maquina virtual Debian corriendo con bitnami en virtual box, donde los servicios de  apache, mysql y php se encuentran corriendo como se ve a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También el firewall no tiene ninguna restricción de acceso como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar el comando `curl`  dentro de la máquina a la url `http://localhost/` este devuelve un contenido en html. Ahora bien, lo que quiero es realizar peticiones desde el anfitrión (host) hacia el invitado (guest),así que configure la red de la máquina en la opción de tipo NAT y en el reenvió de puertos lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde se presenta el problema, cuando hago una petición desde el anfitrión(host) a través del navegador `http://localhost:8080/` me aparece el error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN, cuando uso la consola o terminal dice "could not resolve host". No se que puedo estar haciendo mal, ya que en el caso del puerto asignado para ssh me funciona perfectamente, y en el host tampoco estoy corriendo alguna aplicación en los puertos 8080 u 8081.

Comment: Te funciona con `http://127.0.0.1:8080`?

Comment: muestra el mensaje "Recv failure: Connection was reset"

Answer (score 0):

sucedió algo completamente curioso y no entiendo la razón. Resulta que sobre la maquina virtual instale el entorno de escritorio genome, dado que no tenia ninguno. La razón por la que lo hice fue porque quería ver el sitio WordPress funcionando en dicha maquina. Después  de completar la instalación accedí localmente y desde el host y funciona correctamente. Como se puede observar desde el host accedo desde el puerto 8080 y me redirige al puerto 80 de la maquina virtual. No hice ningún cambio en la configuración de firewall o redirección de puertos de virtual box.
Para dar mas detalles, en virtual box use un archivo `.ova` que ofrece el sitio de [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/virtual-machine) y lo importe, esta no tiene entorno gráfico y por eso lleve a cabo la instalación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]